# ReactJS: looping through object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, mapping

Im new to react and Im confused how to map my object to my react component

my object looks like this

```
const LinkValue = [{
        'XYZ':['About Us','Core Values','Careers','contact Us']
    },{
        'Help':['Payments','Saved Cards','FAQ']
    }]
```

React component

```
const LinkLoop = map(LinkValue,(value,key)=>{
        return(
                <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" key={key}>
                <div className="quicklinks-card">
                    <h3>{value[key]}</h3>
                    <ul className="list-unstyled">

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">value[key]</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">value[key]</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">value[key]</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
```

Im not clear how to loop through my object, also my object values is not of same length

Expected Output

```
<div className="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div className="quicklinks-card">
        <h3>XYZ</h3>
            <ul className="list-unstyled">

                  <li>
                       <a href="#">About Us</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                        <a href="#">Core Values</a>
                  </li>
                   <li>
                        <a href="#"> Careers </a>
                   </li>
                  <li>
                        <a href="#">contact Us</a>
                   </li>
             </ul>
     </div>
</div>
<div className="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div className="quicklinks-card">
        <h3>XYZ</h3>
            <ul className="list-unstyled">


                  <li>
                        <a href="#"> Payments </a>
                  </li>
                   <li>
                        <a href="#"> Saved Cards </a>
                   </li>
                  <li>
                        <a href="#"> FAQ </a>
                   </li>
             </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have loop through my object and place it my component..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: bit confused with your code I think `value[key]` gives array, which is not good for `<a>` tag. Can you post expected output?

Comment: Will each object in you array have a single key followed by an array or there can be multiple of them

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have added my expected output. Hope this makes things clear

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri. Yes, my object has a single key and has array of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `Object.keys(obj)[0]` to get the first key and then from those keys use `map` to map over the array

```js
    const LinkValue = [{
            'XYZ':['About Us','Core Values','Careers','contact Us']
        },{
            'Help':['Payments','Saved Cards','FAQ']
        }]

    const LinkLoop = LinkValue.map((value,key)=>{
            return(
                     <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" key={key}>
                            <div className="quicklinks-card">
                            <h3>{Object.keys(value)[0]}</h3>
                             <ul className="list-unstyled">
                                  {value[Object.keys(value)[0]].map((obj, idx) => (
                                      <li key={idx}>
                                          <a href="#">{obj}</a>
                                       </li>

                                  ))}

                             </ul>
                        </div>
                   </div>
            )
        })
```

Comment: @PriyeshKumar OP says that inner object has only one key and hence I modified the answer to not to loop over the keys but to just use the first one

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Can i use "value[Object.keys(value)[key]]" instead of..... value[Object.keys(value)[0]]

Comment: @Coeus since you need only the first key from the object you should be using [0] and not [key]

Comment: no I wanted it to dynamic..i wanted both the object to be displayed..can you modify the answer..this will of great help

Comment: Buddy let me explain, both of your object will be diplayed, since you mapping over the array of objects with the `LinkValue.map()` and that value here is the obejct which contains a single key, so I am getting that key with Object.keys(value)[0] and then mapping over the array obtained from the object with this key